# Geckofx 60 accept third party cookies

Tags: cookies, geckofx

I recently upgraded from geckofx 40 (which seems to have third party cookies enabled by default) to geckofx 60 which does not. I cannot find the setting to enable them.

I've looked through all the `network.cookie.*` settings and can't find a way to turn on third party cookies.

Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: This was a bug in the 0.11 geckofx alpha version. This is now fixed. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/issues/2/cookies-not-working-on-geckofx-60

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I've switched to Cefsharp now, but good to know anyway, so thank you.